# Storing data on EBS vs EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm having trouble understanding whether my data on an AWS EC2 instance is on the EC2 itself or on the attached EBS. I used `scp` to copy some files from my computer to the folder `/home/ec2-user`. At this point is the data already on the EBS volume or just on EC2? The EC2 lists `/dev/sda1` as a block device. Does this mean the files are only on EBS when moved to that directory? Also, the directory `/dev` exists but `sda1` does not.

Comment: This should be moved to Server Fault.  All the storage is on an EBS volume.  Both the primary disk you copied from an AMI and any secondary EBS volume you add and mount.  Check to see if any secondary EBS volume you've attached is at /dev/xvd*, then you'll need to mount it to some filesystem location, e.g. /mnt.

Comment: Take a look in the console.  When you select the instance, in the lower window there should be two things - "Root device type" will tell you if it is EBS or instance store.  That will match when you select the device name like /dev/xvda.  If you've mounted additional devices then they will be under "Block Devices" and each of them can tell you if it's EBS or instance store.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This helps a lot.